# Django Rest Framework Returning a single value

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, aggregate

If i had a model as below, how would i return the total number of miles in the DB? If i use the aggregate function then it will work, but it will iterate through all objects and give me the total next to those objects.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Rec(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    miles = models.IntegerField()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class SummarySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    total_miles = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_miles(self, obj):
        return Rec.objects.filter(name=obj.name).aggregate(Sum('miles'))
```

**views.py**

```
class SummaryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SummarySerializer
    queryset = Rec.objects.all()
```

**current output**

```
[{'total':1000, 'total':1000, 'total':1000.... etc}]
```

**Desired output (one instance of the value)**

```
[{'total_miles': 1000}]
```

Comment: What is the error of the aggregates?

Comment: Sorry ... been working with too many code samples - there is no error it will just repeat the same info for every object in the DB: [{total:1000, total:1000, total:1000...etc}].  I've updated the original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django aggregate returns a dict(), When you aggregate data you should add a key to it and then spit the key

```
 def get_total_miles(self, obj):
        return Rec.objects.filter(name=obj.name).aggregate(sum_miles=Sum('miles'))['sum_miles']
```

Comment: This works great THANK YOU! I ended up moving this logic to the views so that i had access to the request object coming in (for parameters) and so I had all my logic contained in the views file.  Is that best practice?  Also i upvoted your answer but don't have enough reputation for it to show :)

Comment: Well i do it this way in the documentation there are some examples using it, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates I think that it is a correct approach to define the keyword, because django adds keywods on its own and if the keyword is too_long it wont be very pretty code